# Why does the original Nintendo take 9V AC instead of 9V DC?

Tags: ac, dc

I have found an old Nintendo NES 9V wall adapter which is not an AC DC adapter.  It's an AC AC adapter. It's the first time I've seen an AC adapter that ouputs alternating current. Why did Nintendo run with that?

Comment: Related question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/52216/why-do-some-power-adapters-output-an-ac-voltage

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The NES requires a 13V and a 5V supply. The details are in the schematic:

[image: schematic of NES power input]

*[full schematics and image source](https://web.archive.org/web/20150803044556/http://www.freeinfosociety.com/electronics/schemview.php?id=2405)*

The 13V supply is used for the video and audio outputs where 5V would not have provided sufficient headroom, especially considering the less sophisticated electronics of the day.

These days we take regulated supplies as the norm because switching supplies are cheaper (by eliminating the need for a large transformer), but that wasn't true in 1983. Then, the cheapest power supply you could get was just a transformer, which means AC output. While they certainly could have selected a wall wart that rectified and filtered to output DC, there just wasn't much to be gained. Since there was already a need for a power board to generate 13V and 5V, the cost of sticking a rectifier and a few extra capacitors on it is very small, and there's plenty of room in the NES for them to fit.

Comment: Interestingly, many NES power supply replacement parts these days are labelled AC/DC converter. This strikes me as a very different power source compared to AC/AC. How could they be compatible ?

Answer (score 1):

Well an ac adapter is cheaper than a dc, it could just be a transformer in there.   If they were just going to regulate all the supplies again inside the box no need to have a regulated input.

Comment: Rectification and regulation are two different things.  Until the recent era of compact switchers, it was normal for wallwarts to be unregulated, regardless if they output AC or DC.

Comment: No way are you serious?  I had never heard this...  The point of the story is that it can be cheaper this way especially back in the day.  Obviously you have to rectify as well but you don't have to pay for a fully regulated supply you don't need.

Comment: I think Chris Stratton is quite right. Every non-SMPS, DC-output wall-wart I've opened (must have been 10-12 models) had only a rectifier in it; most of the old ones have 4 diodes and capacitor on a small PCB. For the newer/cheaper ones I've seen a single bridge rectifier IC point-soldered with the capacitor on its output.